# Firefox profile setup throws error in protractor with selenium webdriver configuration

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

```
var q = require("q");
var FirefoxProfile = require("firefox-profile");
var makeFirefoxProfile = function(preferenceMap) {

    var deferred = q.defer();
    var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

    for (var key in preferenceMap) {
        firefoxProfile.setPreference(key, preferenceMap[key]);
    };

    firefoxProfile.encoded(function (encodedProfile) {
        var capabilities = {
            browserName: "firefox",
            directConnect: true,
            firefox_profile: encodedProfile
        };

        deferred.resolve(capabilities);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};


exports.config = {
   specs:specs,
   getMultiCapabilities: function() {
       return q.all([
           makeFirefoxProfile(
               {
                   "browser.download.folderList": 2,
                   "browser.download.dir": "/path/to/save/downloads",
                   "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk": "application/zip"
               }
           )
       ]);
   },

  // ...
}
```

It throws the following error:

> ERROR - failed loading configuration file protractor.conf.js
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/configParser.js:183
>       throw e;
>             ^ Error: Cannot find module 'q'

Please share your views to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `q` and `firefox-profile` modules installed:

```
npm install q firefox-profile --save-dev
```